# how to disable sound of (un-)muting in webex (41.6.7.16)

Tags: webex

I'm new to webex. Every time I mute or unmute myself, it plays some music to make sure I don't hear the meeting itself. How to turn this pointless feature off? I saw notice, that if I go to main-menu->participant->entry and exit tone and set it to off it should stop. Similar when scheaduling meeting. There are just 2 problems with that: sometimes this menu is disabled and I cannot untick that (which is super useful to enforce bothering atendees) and second, it does not work; even if I untick it, (un-)muting sound is still present. Somehow it even picks up hw button and makes sure, that it will beep even if I try to bypass annoying webex beeping (without webex it behaves normally).

Is there a way how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

#### how can I disable the sound of (un-)muting in webex?

It's not currently possible:

> There is no setting to adjust the volume or disable the mute notification in a Webex meeting. You can vote for a toggle of mute/unmmute notification feature here https://ciscocollabcustomer.ideas.aha.io/ideas/WXCUST-I-3608

Source: [Solved: Re: "Beep" notification when muting / unmuting - Cisco Community](https://community.cisco.com/t5/webex-meetings-and-webex-app/quot-beep-quot-notification-when-muting-unmuting/m-p/4127650#M850)

There is an outstanding feature request:

> **Make a Toggle for Local Mute/Unmute Tone**
>
> We like the tone for accessibility but also have many reasonable complaints raised by those it annoys. Other meeting software does not have the tone and it makes adoption tougher not having a control on this. Here is an example of feedback I receive:
>
> It's unnecessary. No other meeting platform (Teams, Zoom, even Skype!) has a mandatory signal to let us know that we are muted, and we do just fine without that!
>
> It's distracting. Though it doesn't fully drown out the other speaker's audio, it takes attention away from it, which can make comprehension difficult for people with hearing loss and for English language learners.
>
> It's inconvenient. Webex prides itself on being customizable, e.g., I can decide if there is a sound when people arrive/leave, so why can't I customize this basic of a setting?

Source: [Make a Toggle for Local Mute/Unmute Tone | User Community Feedback](https://ciscocollabcustomer.ideas.aha.io/ideas/WXCUST-I-3608)

The best thing you can do right now is vote for the feature request.

Comment: thanks. Teams cannot do copy&paste(also several years old "request for improvement" ), webex cannot shut up. It's just making every day a little bit brighter. At least - thanks to your answer - I don't have to waste time searching for it.

Comment: @MartinMucha "Teams cannot do copy&paste"??? I use teams all day at work. Copy and paste work fine for me ...

Comment: really, it's open&neglected RFE. Try to copy multiple messages spanning more than 1 page. Copying 1 message usually works, several messages sometimes, multiple messages mostly not. Workaround is to make window really big (bigger than screen) and move with whole window avoiding scrolling. This sometimes help. But this is maybe only on linux, I don't know, I didnt used teams on windows yet.